# ajax progressive enhancement: How to prevent multiple requests

Tags: ajax, preventdefault, progressive-enhancement

Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing.

I have a standard menu like so:

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li><a href="/link1.html">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="/link2.html">Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="/link3.html">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

On document ready, I'm calling a function to stop the links from going anywhere and binding click events for ajax loads:

```
$('#menu a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var link = $(this).attr('href');

        $.ajax({
                url: link,
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (html) {

                   AJAX STUFF HERE
                }
        });

});
```

My question is what is a good way to prevent multiple requests.

My first try at this, on click, I have a conditional that checks for a class of "loading". If false it adds the class of "loading" to the container of html that I'm replacing and removing the class on ajax success. This works fine, but has poor performance if the user tries to make multiple requests. I'm guessing this is because it's firing an event each time, even if it's not doing much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your code to use "on" with a specific class:

```
$('#menu').on('click', 'a', (function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var link = $(this);
  if (!link.hasClass('loading') {
    link.addClass('loading');
    var href = link.attr('href');
    $.ajax({
      url: href,
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function (html) {
        // AJAX STUFF HERE
      },
      complete: function() { link.removeClass('loading'); }
    });
  }
});
```

You only have one binding now (more efficient) and it will take the ajax action when the anchor does not have a "loading" class. Note that this will require jQuery 1.7+

[jQuery `.on()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

**EDIT** (x2)

Per Dan's comments, the above code was updated for correctness. That said, you could make this slightly more efficient by changing the html and js to the following. Note that this means that users without JavaScript will simply follow the links.

```
<ul id='menu'>
  <li><a href='/link1.php'>Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='/link2.php'>Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href='/link3.php'>Link 3</a></li>
</ul>

$('#menu')
  .on('click', 'a:not(.loading)', (function () {
    var link = $(this).addClass('loading');
    $.ajax({
      url: link.attr('data-href'),
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function (html) {
        // AJAX STUFF HERE
      },
      complete: function() { link.removeClass('loading'); }
    })
  })
  // Remove anchor tag href to eliminate possibility of following the link versus ajax load
  .find('a').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-href', $(this).attr('href')).removeAttr('href');
  });
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the problem with this is that if the user clicks multiple times, the href will cause a full page load because nothing is stopping it.

Comment: That's what the `e.preventDefault();` is for, prevents the default action, which for an anchor tag with an `href` attribute is to follow the link.

Comment: I understand that, but here's what's happening:

On click checks if it's an 'a' tag and doesn't have a class of loading, if true you preventDefault and add a class of loading.

If you double click, it ignores preventDefault because it has a class of loading. 

I don't think it's preventing multiple requests if the user clicks multiple links either.

Comment: Heh... good catch Dan! My mistake, but you can still use the `on()` binding to at least make the event handling slightly more efficient. I'll update my code.

Comment: And actually, now that I think about it, you could just remove the anchor altogether to avoid this. Again, I'll update the code.

Comment: I was thinking about the same thing with removing the href, but instead of removing it, just replace it with a data-href attribute and read from that. I'm not sure if that's any good for bots and crawlers, but I can't think of any other solution that would be better.

Comment: Almost what I was talking about. It should come on the page with href="/url", then use javascript to replace them with data-href. This way if javascript is disabled, then the links will still work. I'll give you a check because you helped, but I think you should add that last part for other people looking at this who don't read our comments.